# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in jQuery - why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my php code

```
$p1 = explode(',',$pprod_material->p1);
$p11 = json_encode($p1);
```

This is my Html code

```
<input  style="margin-left:-10px;"   type="checkbox" onClick="qst_check_ingri(<?php echo $p11; ?>);"  id="<?php echo $id44;  ?>" value="<?= $id44; ?>" name="extra_check" >
```

This is my click function in script

```
function qst_check_ingri (val) 
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(val));
    }
```

This is my view-source code output

```
<input style="margin-left:-10px;" class="badgebox" type="checkbox" onclick="qst_check_ingri('[" 1","4","7","10","13","16","18","21","24","27","30","33","36",""]');"="" id="4-e1" value="4-e1" name="extra_check">
```

I don't why I'm getting this error from my view code is fine still it shows

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 0):

pass your php value in single quote

```
onClick="qst_check_ingri('<?php echo $p11; ?>');"
```

Comment: what is your value for php variable

Comment: Sir It's an array which im converting it to json to pass it click function

Comment: Out put ["1","4","7","10","13","16","18","21","24","27","30","33","36",""]

Comment: you can pass the value in comma seperated string and convert again in php file